# ZCO14001("Video Game") in Java: Simulating a crane and finding final number of blocks in each stack

Tags: java

Here's the problem: https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14001

Problem statement(modified) from CodeChef:

> You are playing a video game in which several stacks of boxes are lined up on the floor, with a crane on top to rearrange the boxes, as shown in the picture below.
>
> The crane supports the following commands:
>
> - Move one position left (does nothing if already at the leftmost position)
> - Move one position right (does nothing if already at the rightmost position)
> - Pick up a box from the current stack (does nothing if the crane already has a box)
> - Drop a box on the current stack (does nothing if the crane doesn't already have a box)
>
> Further, there is a limit H on the number of boxes on each stack. If a 'drop' command would result in a stack having more than H boxes, the crane ignores this drop command. If the current stack has no boxes, a 'pick up' command is ignored.
>
> You are given the initial number of boxes in each stack and the sequence of operations performed by the crane. You have to compute the final number of boxes in each stack.
>
> ### Input format
>
> - Line 1 : The width of the game (the number of stacks of boxes), N, followed by the max height H of each stack.
> - Line 2 : N integers, the initial number of boxes in each stack, from left to right. Each number is ≤ H.
> - Line 3 : A sequence of integers, each encoding a command to the crane.
>
>   The commands are encoded as follows:
>
>   1 : Move left
>
>   2 : Move right
>
>   3 : Pick up box
>
>   4 : Drop box
>
>   0 : Quit
> - The command Quit (0) appears exactly once, and is the last command.
> - The initial position of the crane is above the leftmost stack, with the crane not holding any box.
>
> ### Output format
>
> A single line with N integers, the number of boxes in each stack, from left to right.
>
> ### Input-size restrictions
>
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
> - 1 ≤ H ≤ 10^8.

I'm looking for:

- Tips on how to make this more maintainable, better programming practices etc.

**EDIT 1**: As pointed out by multiple people, I have edited my question to include the revised source code with improvements from @Ke Li. To clarify, my original solution was functional, but did not pass large values(due to my very convoluted implementation), so I see what you guys are pointing out.

**EDIT 2**: Included problem statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class VideoGame {
    private int system[];
    private int currentStack; // Zero-indexed stack number
    private boolean hasBlock; // Whether the crane currently has a block
    public int width; // Width of problem
    public int height; // Height of problem

    public VideoGame( int width, int height ) {
        system = new int[ width ];
        currentStack = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.hasBlock = false;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        if( currentStack == 0 ) return;
        // System.out.print( "The position of the crane was moved from " + currentStack );
        currentStack--;
        // System.out.println( " to " + currentStack + "( moveLeft() )" );
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        if( currentStack == width - 1 ) return;
        // System.out.print( "The position of the crane was moved from " + currentStack );
        currentStack++;
        // System.out.println( " to " + currentStack + "( moveRight() )" );
    }

    public void drop() {
        if( system[ currentStack ] == height ) return;
        if( !hasBlock ) return; // If no block lifted, do nothing.

        // System.out.println( "A block was dropped at [" + highestEmpty( currentStack ) + ", " + currentStack + "]" );
        system[ currentStack ]++;
        hasBlock = false;
    }

    public void pick() {
        if( system[ currentStack ] == 0 ) return;
        if( hasBlock ) return;

        // System.out.println( "A block was picked from [" + ( highestEmpty( currentStack ) + 1 ) + ", " + currentStack + "]" );
        system[ currentStack ]--;
        hasBlock = true;
    }

    public void fillStack( int stack, int crates ) {
        system[ stack ] = crates;
    }

    public int countStack( int stack ) {
        return system[ stack ];
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        int w = scanner.nextInt();
        int h = scanner.nextInt();
        VideoGame vg = new VideoGame( w, h );

        for( int i = 0; i < vg.width; i++ ) {
            int numberOfCrates = scanner.nextInt();
            vg.fillStack( i, numberOfCrates );
        }

        while( true ) {
            int command = scanner.nextInt();
            if( command == 0 ) break; // The 'QUIT' command

            switch ( command ) {
                case 1:
                    vg.moveLeft();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vg.moveRight();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    vg.pick();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    vg.drop();
                    break;
            }
        }

        for( int j = 0; j < vg.width; j++ ) {
            System.out.print( vg.countStack( j ) );
            System.out.print( " " );
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993/41243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RE(Runtime error) is because your program is trying to allocate too much memory. You must consider the input data range(you can find it in the problem description):

```
 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000

 1 ≤ H ≤ 100000000
```

So there is something we need to change in your code. Firstly, we need simplify the program. When we do `drop` and `pick`, we reduce the stack size by one actually. So we don't need the 2D-array here. We only need one-D array to simulate the stack size for each position.

For `move-left` and `move-right` operations, there is no difference with your code.

But for `drop` and `pick`, we can simplify the logic.

For `drop`, you only need to check if current stack is full:

`size of current stack  == height`

For `pick`, you only need to check if current stack is empty:

`size of current stack == 0`

This changes will reduce the required memory and time complexity a lot and simplify the code logic.

Here is a changed code from yours:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class VideoGame {

//    private boolean system[][]; // True: crate; False: no crate
    private int system[];
    private int currentStack; // Zero-indexed stack number
    private boolean hasBlock; // Whether the crane currently has a block
    public int width; // Width of problem
    public int height; // Height of problem


    public VideoGame(int width, int height) {
    //           system = new boolean[height][width];
        system = new int[width];

        currentStack = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.hasBlock = false;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        if (currentStack == 0) return;
        // System.out.print( "The position of the crane was moved from " + currentStack );
        currentStack--;
        // System.out.println( " to " + currentStack + "( moveLeft() )" );
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        if (currentStack == width - 1) return;
        // System.out.print( "The position of the crane was moved from " + currentStack );
        currentStack++;
        // System.out.println( " to " + currentStack + "( moveRight() )" );
    }

    public void drop() {
        if (system[currentStack] == height) return;

        if (!hasBlock) return; // If no block lifted, do nothing.

        system[currentStack] ++;
        hasBlock = false;
    }

    public void pick() {
        if (system[currentStack] == 0) return;
        if (hasBlock) return;

        system[currentStack]--;
        hasBlock = true;
    }


    public void fillStack(int stack, int crates) {
        system[stack] = crates;
    }

    public int countStack(int stack) {
        return system[stack];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int w = scanner.nextInt();
        int h = scanner.nextInt();
        VideoGame vg = new VideoGame(w, h);

        for (int i = 0; i < vg.width; i++) {
            int numberOfCrates = scanner.nextInt();
            vg.fillStack(i, numberOfCrates);
        }

        while (true) {
            int command = scanner.nextInt();
            if (command == 0) break; // The 'QUIT' command

            switch (command) {
                case 1:
                    vg.moveLeft();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vg.moveRight();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    vg.pick();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    vg.drop();
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < vg.width; j++) {
            System.out.print(vg.countStack(j));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Amazing, worked like a charm. I'm surprised I complicated this so much. Do you have any comments on the way I approached the problem, the API I used etc?